# creating a basic jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to jQuery plugins, I have followed this [Tutorial](http://css-plus.com/2010/04/how-to-create-a-simple-jquery-plugin/) and have come unstuck with the following code:

```
  if (!($(this).attr('data-mobHigh') === undefined)) {
   $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-mobHigh"));
  }
```

I am initialising the plugin like this

```
        $('img').mezzaraine();
```

I don't what the second `$(this)` reference to change to `img` as I am giving an argument `img` to the plugin in the second line:

```
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("data-mobHigh"));
```

`this`- (an html attribute) also changed to `img`. I need to use `this` instead of 'img'.

How can this be done?

Comment: Your problem could be solved but the wording isn't clear. Can you make it *more* clear?

Comment: I believe the question is, how can this plugin only act on the desired `img` tag, and not all `img` tags in the page.

Comment: Show your full code...

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini post your *full* code..

Comment: Try this instead: lowercase the attribute as it is supposed to be and do `var mobhigh = $(this).data('mobhigh'); if (mobhigh) this.src=mobhigh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store `this` as a local variable.

```
$.fn.mezzaraine = function() {
    var $imgs = this;
    $imgs.each(function(i, img) {
        var $img = $(img); // wrap with $ if you want to chain jQuery methods

        // things you are going to do
    });
}
```

Then reuse the variable rather than wrap with $ every time.

```
if($img.attr('data-mobHigh') !== undefined) {
    $img.attr("src", $img.attr("data-mobHigh"));
}
```

Moreover, as you are using dataset, jQuery provides a better API

```
if($img.data('mobHigh') !== undefined) {
    $img.attr("src", $img.data("mobHigh"));
}
```

Comment: @Thanks leo. Vote if you think question is  quality.

Comment: `var $img = $(this);` should be `var $img = this;` -- `this` is already a jQuery collection so as it is the target element is being double wrapped like this `$( $( targetElement ) )`.

Comment: @PeterKA Oops, you are right, thank you for reminding.

Comment: @LeoDeng if i do  var $img = this; instead of var $img = $(this); it dosen't work... Why??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini I've updated the answer to add `each` iteration. I forgot one thing that you may have multiple `<img>` tags.

Comment: @Leo Can you please explain what you did. i am kind of newbie here.

Comment: Oh you mean i don't' have to manually change the @img you just iterated each to change right...

Comment: In my code, `$imgs` is a collection of your elements returned by `$('img')`. Since you may have more than 1 `<img>` tag in HTML, I chained a `each` method with it, means that do the things you want to **every** img in the collection.

Comment: Yep, I guess it's better to apply for jQuery style while writing a plugin. **implicit iteration** is one thing jQuery usually do. For example, `$('p').addClass('cls')` will add the classname to all `<p>` elements, you don't have to iterate the collection by yourself, that's implicit iteration.